Regularity of the weak solution on the cube
Let $Q:=[0,1]^d$ and $g\in L^2(\Omega)$. Consider the PDE :
$$
\begin{cases}
        -\Delta f=g  & \text{in $\Omega$} \\
        f\equiv 0 & \mbox{on $\partial \Omega$.}
    \end{cases}
$$
I know that if $\Omega$ is $C^2$ then we have : $f\in H^2(\Omega)$.
The same holds true if $\Omega=\{z_n>0\}$.
Is this true for $\Omega=Q$ ?

Odd periodic continuation is your friend.

@MichaelRenardy I know some what about that, can you please provide a complet answer. From what  i can tell the proof using odd continuation is simple enought, but I havent seen it in any book, so i assume is something wrong with my understanding

The cube is convex and on convex domains there is optimal $H^2 \cap H^1_0$ regularity for $L^2$ data. See for example the book of Grisvard.

Continue f and g as odd functions of period 2 in all directions. Your problem is then equivalent to the periodic problem, for which regularity is well known.

I changed $\Omega=${$z_n>0$} to $\Omega={z_n>0}$ (coded as Omega=\{z_n>0\}) so that there is proper horizontal spacing and no mismatch of fonts. Notice that if you must write $${}$$ $\Omega={}$something expressed other than in math mode,$${}$$then you can code the MathJax or LaTeX part as \Omega={} (with those curly braces) and then put no space between the MathJax or LaTeX part and the word that follows it, then because of those {curly braces} you will see the proper amount of horizontal space to the right of$\text{ “}{=}\text{”}.$
